# Boost Interprocess | build an memoryHandler

Tags: c++, boost-interprocess

I am trying to build a memoryHandler which allows me to create and manage my shared memory, e.g. I want to create a `managed_memory_object` only once. 
When I construct an segment I want to actually store the return pointer as a member variable in my class, so I can access it without using the find function from boost.

Is there any way to achieve something like this or do I always have to map my shared memory and find my segment with the find function?

thank you for you help

Manu

Example Class:

```
MemHandler::MemHandler(const char* name_p)
{
    size_m = 1024;
    name_m = name_p;
    shm_m{open_or_create, name_m, size_m};
    sharedVar_m = shm_m.construct<int>("sharedValue")(4711);


}
int* MemHandler::getSharedVar()
{
    return sharedVar_m;
}
void MemHandler::setSharedVar(int value)
{
    sharedVar_m = shm_m.construct<int>("sharedValue")(value);
}
```

Comment: Why not changing `name_p` to reference?

Comment: @AlBundy i edited my example, but it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Really, try to provide an MCVE so we got a chance to help you.